# Accidentally formatted hard drive when installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, ubuntu-12.04, format

So, I had Windows 7 on my hard drive. I decided to dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04. I was in a hurry and hit the wrong button, so it wiped out (full format) my Win7 install. It was a NTFS drive, but was formatted to ext4. I didn't realize it until about an hour of usage. There was lots of important data on there. Is there any hope of recovery? EDIT: As soon as I realized that the data was lost, I shut the computer down.

Comment: First, stop using the drive and switch to a linux live CD. *Now*. Then search SuperUser for data recovery questions.

Comment: testdisk. immediately. be sure to recover to a differant physical disk of the same or greater capacity.

Comment: Knowledge through experience...priceless! @weatherkid, welcome to the club.

Answer (score 4):

Your only hope of recovery of the data is to use those fine backups you have made on your windows 7 system.  Hopefully, they are safe and fairly current.  Otherwise, the answer is pretty much NO your content is Lost.

If you wish to spend a lot of money to a data recovery company, perhaps some or most of the content can be restored.  But you have to weigh the cost against the value of the information.

Comment: Data Recovery companies can't recover overwritten data from modern hard drives. What wasn't overwritten might be salvageable, but it's probably not much at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to @Frank Thomas and try `testdisk` - which you can get [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) - but pull the drive out and put it in a USB enclosure or non-boot SATA port.

You've likely lost some data, but you can try to recover what you can using the above.

Comment: I think I have a USB enclosure lying around somewhere... I will try that.

Comment: I tried testdisk, but it couldn't recover anything.